# Django save ImageField to ForeignKey object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save images in a folder and bind it to another database object using ForeignKey, so I can look it up later. I have the code for grabbing the images in the folder and now i'm just trying to save them.

My current error is:

```
'ImageFileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Models.py

```
class Usertasks(models.Model):
    TaskID = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TaskStatus = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="missing")

class TaskImages(models.Model):
    UserTasks = models.ForeignKey(Usertasks, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
def task_info(request, taskid):
    task = Usertasks.objects.get(TaskID=taskid)
    files = os.listdir(task.OutputPath)
    fullpath = task.OutputPath
    print(files)
    for img in files:
        fullpath = os.path.abspath(img)
        with open(fullpath, 'rb') as f: 
            data = File(f)
            TaskImages.image.save(img, data, True, UserTasks=task)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/task.html', {'path':fullpath, 'image':files})
```

Comment: You shouldn't use uppercase in your class properties names, it's confusing.

Comment: @Loïc do you mean the `TaskID` columns and such?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Those are class properties, you should use snake_case : task_id, see PEP-8 :
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables
Also since UserTasks is a foreign key, there will be only one taks attached to that TaskImage row, so it should be named : user_task.